# how to properly loop from an external list to use inside mutate in dplyr

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I am trying to fix parts of a loop function

I have long lists ( such as 'ee') which I have created containing strings of characters and regex. with the structure below

> ee <- c("retard+$", "aluminium\d+", "potassium+$", "ID+$",.......,"chloride+$",)

NB: I have put the regex there on purpose

I wanted to take each element of this list and substitute with "BB00" in rather large dataframes (small portion is below, the useful column is "c")

```
dput(df)
structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8), b = c(2011, 2012, 2010, 1995, 1998, 2011, 2011), c = c("enemy ID9", "John potassium", "chloride misch", "malchloride", "retardfalling", "friendretard", "use to beID10")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

So I tried to create a function which takes a list,and loops by passing each element to gsub() within  mutate() of dplyr as below

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr) library(tidytext) library(tidyr)


strpDetach<- function(x){
  for(j in x){
    df1=df %>% mutate(c = gsub(j, "BB00", c,ignore.case=TRUE))
    return(df1) }
  }

df2=strpDetach(ee)

dput(df2)
structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8), b = c(2011, 2012, 2010, 1995, 1998, 2011, 2011), c = c("enemy ID9", "John potassium", "chloride misch", "malchloride", "retardfalling", "friendBB00", "use to beID10")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Apparently, only the first element in the list works

Modifying the function in another way (to directly take each element of list) as below:

```
strpDetach<- function(j){df %>% mutate(c = gsub(j, "BB00", c,ignore.case=TRUE))}
for( j in ee){
      for (i in 1:ncol(df)) { 
             c=df[,3]
              df1=strpDetach(j)
          }
  }

dput(df1)
structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8), b = c(2011, 2012, 2010, 1995, 1998, 2011, 2011), c = c("enemy ID9", "John potassium", "chloride misch", "malBB000", "retardfalling", "friendretard", "use to beID10")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Only the last element in the list works

My question is where am I doing something wrong in the looping ?

Many Thanks for reading my long essay!!

An expected output would be:

```
dput(df1)
structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8), b = c(2011, 2012, 2010, 1995, 1998, 2011, 2011), c = c("enemy BB000", "JohnBB000", "chloride misch", "malBB000", "retardfalling", "friendBB000", "use to beBB000")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thanks @akrun I have added that

Comment: I posted a solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this without an r-style loop by using a regex symbol `|` which translates to `or`.

I can't tell if your regex is the way you mean it to be. `"retard+$"` means `retard` with one or more d's and then the end of the string. So `retarddddd` would match but `retardfalling` would not match.

```
# combine all the regex checks by collapsing them into a single string with a pipe in-between.
ee2 <- paste0(ee,collapse = "|")
df4 <- df %>%
  mutate(c = stringr::str_replace_all(c,ee2,"BB00"))

#a    b              c
#1 2011      enemy ID9
#2 2012      John BB00
#3 2010 chloride misch
#4 1995        malBB00
#6 1998  retardfalling
#7 2011     friendBB00
#8 2011  use to beID10
```

Comment: `string_replace_all` is what I'm used to and I'm familiar with it. The same regex should work in a `sub` but I don't always remember how to do vector inputs to sub and grep so I didn't try here.

Comment: Many Thanks @Adam Sampson .  Excellent way to incorporate mutate. I initially played around with using pipes and later with  str_replace but never thought of incorporating mutate. Thanks . The regex are there deliberately

Answer (score 1):

Here, we need only a single loop instead of nested loop as the `x` in `sub` is vectorized

```
ee <- c('ID\\d+$', 'potassium$', 'chloride$', 'retard$')
for(pat in ee) df$c <- sub(pat, "BB000", df$c)
```

As the replacement is occurring once in each element i.e. at the end (`$`) of the string, we need only `sub` (`gsub`- global substitution).  Along with that, the changed column is updated in each loop so that it is updated in each run

---

Also, as the question is about `dplyr`, we can update the datasets in each `for` loop

```
library(dplyr)
for(pat in ee) {

    df <- df %>%
             mutate(c = str_replace(c, pat, "BB000"))
  }
```

Comment: Many Thanks @akrun ,  the first , using  'sub' on a single loop does the work.  the second, using dplyr in that for loop executes only for the last element in the list,  just like my post, (I assume the 'str_replace' is the same one in stringr )

Comment: I could not find a way to click this  one too as an answer. The first part does the same work !!!